# Is there a way to set number of shards and replicas while using JavaEsSpark api in spark

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, rdd

I am using JavaEsSpark for wring in ElasticSearch in spark, I want to change the default no_of_shards of elasticsearch while index creation.

Below is the line of code that i am using that creates the index as well as write the rdd in it but how can i set no of shards in this?

```
 JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(stringRDD, "index_name/docs");
```

I have also tried setting in sparkConf object but still not working.

Comment: You could simply consider setting up an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) directly in ES with the correct settings.